# Concurrent Modification exception when i compile my code,

Tags: java, arrays, loops, concurrentmodification

I've been given this exercise to do and I'm struggling to understand why I keep getting concurrent modification error when I compile my code.

> "If the list contains a film with a title that matches the parameter
>   title then update it's length and genre. If no match is found create a
>   new film and add it to the list."

I've managed to check if there's a match for title however when there isn't one I'm unable to successfully add a new film to my array. Here's the code I wrote:

```
public void updateLengthAndGenre(String title, int length, String genre) {
    ArrayList<Film> output = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean found = false;

    for (Film film : films) {
        if (film.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            found = true;
            film.setGenre(genre);
            film.setLength(length);
        }
    }

    for (Film film : films) {
        if (!found) {
            films.add(new Film(title, length, genre));
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why I keep getting this error and also give me some advice how to remedy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this exceotion is because you're trying to simultaneously add to a collection while iterating over it. You cannot do this. In your case, it doesn't seem like you actually even have to do this at all.

```
public void updateLengthAndGenre(String title, int length, String genre) {
    ArrayList<Film> output = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Film film : films) {
      if (film.getTitle().equals(title)) {
          film.setGenre(genre);
          film.setLength(length);
          return;
      }
    }

    films.add(new Film(title, length, genre));  // synchronize if you're multithreading
}
```

This has the same effect. If you absolutely need to add to a collection while iterating, you can use a `java.util.ListIterator`.

```
ListIterator<Film> filmIter = films.listIterator();
while(filmIter.hasNext()){
    if( /* some condition */){
        fillmIter.add(new Film(title, length, genre));
    }
    filmIter.next(); // example only.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much both suggestions worked.